# Using Blue Prism, how do i store a single excel cell as a data item?

Tags: blueprism

This Cell is B2 and is a number.

I thought of using Collection Manipulation but this asks for a Field Name, which i don't have.

Can you use a cell reference instead?

Comment: field name = column name

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Get Cell Value` action of the default MS Excel VBO to retrieve the contents of a particular cell reference:

[image: Inputs]

[image: Output]

You can then use a calculation stage to translate the text you retrieve into the data item into a Number data item using the `ToNumber()` function:

[image: Conversion using calculation stage]